# Two Data types or role on one input

Tags: php, jquery, session-cookies, jquery-cookie

I want to implement cookies on an input, in order for it to work, I need to use data-type="date". 
The problem is I am using jquery to design a toggle button and they use data-role="flipswitch". Is there a way that I can have two types or roles so that I can retrieve cookies and still use the Jquery library to get the styling?

```
'<form> \
                         <label for="togggle_test"></label>\
                         <span class="off">testOne</span>\
                        <input id="togggle_test" <?php echo (isset($_COOKIE['userChoice']) && !empty($_COOKIE['userChoice'] ) && ($_COOKIE['userChoice'])== "TEST") ? "checked" : "";?>  onchange="performToggleAction(this)" data-type="date" type="checkbox"></input>\
                    <span class="on"> testTwo  </span>\
                </form>';
```

Answer (score -1):

The first role you need it, set it and after using that, change role with JavaScript or jQuery and use the second role.

Comment: There is no other way of doing this?

Comment: Why not use both roles،Must work with both roles،I already use two rols and there is not problem